Can false sharing happen in Direct-Mapped Cache?
If each address in memory is directly mapped to deterministic location in cache, cache coherence is not needed because all thread that access share data share the same cache.
Ie. Within the context of share data. One thread writing to cache does not necessary mean that cache have to flush to memory or that second thread accessing the cache have to fetch from memory. Because the share data is already up to date in cache
The only downside is that access to cache will be sequential missing the point of parallelism. Is this understanding correct?
struct SharedData {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
void threadFunc(int &var) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        var++;
    }
}


int main() {
    SharedData data;

    std::thread threads[NUM_THREADS];
    threads[0] = std::thread(threadFunc, std::ref(data.a));
    threads[1] = std::thread(threadFunc, std::ref(data.b));
    threads[2] = std::thread(threadFunc, std::ref(data.c));
    threads[3] = std::thread(threadFunc, std::ref(data.d));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

For example , from the example above, once shareData is loaded into cache, all 4 thread will use the same cache line instead of 4 separate cache line.
Is my understanding correct?

Note compiler can optimize your function more then you expect: https://godbolt.org/z/3dMqT96ne and as a result your test code can be invalid.

After you will address problems with threadFunc yes you will have false sharing.

"cache coherence is not needed because all thread that access share data share the same cache" — that describes a scenario where no false sharing can occur.  For false sharing you need at least 2 separate caches cooperating to work on shared data.

As @MarekR pointed out the compiler will optimize your thread function. In this case cutting it down to single opcode (+ return). Even more complex code will most likely have the compiler load var into a register and keep it there, that is until you add one bit of code too much and suddenly you get a memory access all over the place. An easy fix to false sharing and this sudden death of parallelity is to A) not use references in the first place or B) copy the value into a local variable at the start and write it back at the end.

You seem to be misunderstanding what false sharing is. It has nothing to do with having something mapped multiple times.
Sharing in multithreaded code refers to something getting accessed by multiple threads. In the context of false sharing it looks at the speed penalty of multiple threads sharing access to something.
And here is where the "false" part comes in. Each thread works on its own variable so nothing is shared there. But when memory is accessed in the CPU this accesses data in the L1 cache. And since the L1 cache works with a granularity of a cache line any access will always affect the whole cache line.
Given stack alignment at function entry all 4 of a, b, c, d will likely end up in a single cache line. So access to any of them means the cache line needs to be present and up-to-date in the CPU core that does the access1. This means the cache line always bounces around the CPU cores and access becomes sequential.

The only downside is that access to cache will be sequential missing the point of parallelism. Is this understanding correct?

That is false sharing in other words.
Note: Modern CPUs have more than one L1 cache. L1 cache is generally shared between hardware threads within a core but separate between cores and always separate between sockets. "Because the share data is already up to date in cache" is therefore not applicable.

Footnote 1:  Unless the compiler optimizes the non-atomic / non-volatile variable into a register for the duration of the loop, like we'd expect with optimization enabled.  Registers are per-core private.  Or it could just optimize it to var += 1000; so each thread only does one load and store of its reference arg.  So for actual false sharing when compiling and running on a real CPU, you'd need a debug build or more complicated code that couldn't optimize away the work.

"L1 cache is generally shared between threads" — between threads that run on one core, but there's no guarantee that all threads of one program will run on the same core, of course, meaning separate threads may run on separate cores with separate L1 caches.

@ErikEidt No, between threads (hardware) that are in the same core. The mainboard may have multiple sockets for CPUs. Each CPU then can have a number of cores that run in parallel. Each core then can have multiple threads that run in a time sharing manner (and share resources in the core). Look up hyperthreading for CPU cores. (answer updated to be more clear)

Multi-core CPUs (with multiple physical cores per socket) have been a thing since the mid 2000s.  Each core has its own private L1d / L1i caches.  (And often a private L2 cache).  You don't need multiple sockets to create cache-line ping-pong between threads running simultaneously and accessing different parts of the same line.  (Or the same part of the same line, for true sharing causing contention that you can't avoid with a different data layout.)

Alignment of the asm stack on function entry doesn't imply that SharedData data; will be aligned by 16.  A compiler might choose to align it by 16, but it only has alignof(T) = 4 vs. its sizeof(T) = 16 so a compiler might put it somewhere only 4 or 8 byte aligned, especially if that avoided allocating an extra 16 bytes.  (In that case it might or might not split across a cache line boundary).

It's the first local variable in the function so I think at least gcc/clang will put it first on the stack giving it a 16 byte alignment. But even if the compiler put's the thread first and the struct ends up split across 2 cache lines that means either a 1:3 or 2:2 split. Either way some parts of the struct will share a cache line.

False sharing problem occurs due to cache line size exceeding variable size, and due to having per-core top level cache.
Direct-Mapped cache is cache associativity option, it has nothing to do with false sharing cases, as in your example.
Regardless whether the cache is direct-mapped, fully-associative, or set-associative, all four integers are likely to be in the same cache line, and false sharing will occur. If, however, some of these integers happen to be in adjacent cache lines, no false sharing will occur for that pair with any cache associativity type, as even direct-mapped cache will still map adjacent cache lines differently.
Direct-mapped cache will force eviction in some cases where fully-assiciative cache would not, but this has nothing to do with concurrent threads, as such eviction happens within the current core.

To be more specific, direct-mapped caches can more easily create conflicts (evictions leading to conflict-misses) between two threads accessing different cache lines.  But not adjacent cache lines; those will index different lines unless the index function is non-trivial or the total cache size is only 1 line.

False sharing means, 2 different core, uses the same cacheline but different words/doubles in the cacheline, and they invalidate & get data from the other continuously.
That means you'll pass data from one to another constant after every store operation they made. It doesn't occur due to your associativity.
